# How to remove Oracle database PDB RESTRICTION

Tags: database, oracle, pdb

HI I am facing Database problems with PDB I checked the PDB ORC1PDB is RESTRICTED ...

```
CON_ID     CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
         1 ORC1PDB1                       READ WRITE YES
```

and I am trying to remove the restriction so I read that I need to solve the errors founded after perform the comand:

```
SELECT * FROM pdb_plug_in_violations;
```

I found the error:

> Sync PDB failed with ORA-959 during 'CREATE USER "CREATE USER C##J5DEV_DB" IDENTIFIED By *DE

so I read that I need create this user inside to the PDB session I change the session:

```
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER = ORC1PDB;
```

and tried to recreate the user:

```
CREATE USER C##J5DEV_DB
```

but the result is:

> ORA-65094 invalid local user or role name

I understand that the character ## maybe is invalid but I need to create this user inside the PDB session to remove the restriction how can I do this????